# May I add additional lyrics to a copyright song without claiming any ownership?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, music

A copyright holder has flatly refused my request to add additional lyrics to one of their songs, for use in a private congregational church setting.

Does this mean it is simply illegal?

I have seen several high-profile cases in the pop music world recently where artists have resolved copyright dispute by simply adding other artists as writers - sometimes as a precautionary measure before any complaint has been made! And going a bit further back, The Verve famously were only allowed to release their hit single "Bittersweet Symphony" by giving up all income to the Rolling Stones (whose song they sampled).

Does this imply that I *can* make a derivative work so long as I relinquish any rights to it, or does the original author still have the final say - is listing them as the author merely a politeness they can reject or does it grant me some official position? I couldn't care less if they wanted to claim ownership but I don't understand the rules. A lot of the time in real life it seems artists just 'do it' and then pay some/all the proceeds to the copyright holder but it is important to me I do things correctly.

Comment: For the most part, the law doesn't really care if you "claim ownership" of a copyrighted work; the problem is if you infringe on one of the actual owner's exclusive rights, which includes "public performance." So publicly performing the work without permission is going to violate copyright, regardless of whether you claim ownership.

Comment: I am going a bit off-topic here, but still slightly related, as you may wonder about parody songs, which are in essence songs with modified lyrics, for which no license is required, so why can't you do the same? This is because the author of a parody is expressing their thoughts about the song, for which it requires to reproduce parts or the entire song. For as long as you are doing that, you should be good, but from your description this is not at all the case. Also, simply claiming something as parody is only as good as a judge ultimately agrees it's a parody.

Comment: @Andrei and to be clear - you must parody the original work, not something else. What ["Weird Al" Yankovic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic) does is not parody under copyright law because he uses the music to parody something else and he gets permission from the rights holders. What [2 Live Crew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell_v._Acuff-Rose_Music,_Inc.) did was parody because its target was the original song.

Comment: By the way, you need a licence to perform copyrighted music in your church; its a public performance.

Comment: @DaleM "What "Weird Al" Yankovic does is not parody under copyright law...": That is incorrect.  He gets permission from copyright holders voluntarily, because of his personal sense of ethics, not because it's legally required.  His works are most certainly parody under copyright law.

Comment: What are are we takling about? sheet music? a recorded performace?

Comment: @DaleM to parody the original work is a pleonasm. If a parody song is not about the original song, then it's simply not a parody song. You seem to suggest that using a song o make fun of something is called a parody. I believe you are mistaken.

Comment: @DaleM It's unclear to me how one could make a "sound-alike" track that *does not* comment on the original - no matter what the lyrics of the new song are about, its very existence is inextricably tied to the source material.

Comment: @phoog. Insofar as Weird Al Yankovic is mostly *using* the songs to parody other things, rather than parodying the songs themselves, they probably do *not* count as parody under copyright law. He probably does need to license them.

Answer (score 14):

## general things on copyright

Copyright law is very similar globally, due to the [Berne convention on copyright.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention)

Ány country's copyright law grants the copyright to an author. Copyright is the exclusive right of an author to authorize ("license") *copies, performance, and derivative works*. In case multiple authors jointly create a work, they own the right in their respective parts, or jointly.

The copyright holder can deny making derivatives.

If a derivative is made without authorization, it is copyright infringement. If the author was asked, denied the authorization and it is made anyway, it is wilful copyright infringement.

Relinquishing your rights in the altered work does not make it not copyright infringement. The only way to not commit copyright infringement is to get a license.

Naming the original author of a work you adapted is not just politeness, it is mandatory in all copyrights that follow the Berne convention on copyright.

### Licensing Fees

The Verve's agreement to get the license was specifically to pay all the proceeds to the Rolling Stones, but that was an extraordinary case.

License fees for *recording a cover version* (with the **unaltered** lyrics!) are usually mandatory to be available. for example in the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), it is mandatory to grant a *mechanical license* to create cover recordings for a licensing fee, for which for example the [Harry Fox Agency](https://www.harryfox.com/) is collecting and distributing the required payments and royalties. Those Royalties are about 9.1 cents **per copy** for a sub-5-minute song's recording. This license does **not** allow to alter lyrics.

However, *synchronization* (tone *and* video) is not mandatory to be granted, and those start at a flat 4-digit and are rather open-ended. Without a sync license, you may not make video recordings of a work being performed.

A *public performance* of a work requires a different license. A *performance license* is required for any public performance, and those are not regulated either, but typically not too expensive - yet alteration again is not within the scope of such a license. Granting a performance license is typically handled by Performing Rights Organisations such as ASCAP, BMI, and SESAC, taking the required fees and distributing the royalties.

Making an adaptation or alteration is a derivative work. Making a derivative work requires a license that is different again. Those can only be granted by the copyright holders, and if they say no... Close the folder.

### The price of copyright infringement

Wilful copyright infringement, especially after you were told no, can be super expensive:

- [In the US](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/504), the rightsholder can get 150 000 USD **and** the lawyer fees for willful infringement. The rightsholder can sue in the US if they are there.
- Recoverable costs plus damages are also available [in the UK](https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/w-011-3729?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)#co_anchor_a722496), capped at 60 000 GBP for costs and 500 000 GBP in damages.

Comment: Nitpicking the "naming the original author" point. I am not aware of a specific provision of Berne Convention that requires it. Berne convention require people to abide by the license imposed by the author, if any, or otherwise the author holds all rights to the copy and nobody else has any rights over said copy. Of course, most licenses require naming the original author, but that's a contract matter, not a law matter.

Comment: @Andrei APPENDIX
SPECIAL PROVISIONS REGARDING DEVELOPING COUNTRIES Article IV
Provisions Common to Licenses Under Articles II and III: (3) The name of the author shall be indicated on all copies of the translation or reproduction published under a license granted under Article II or Article III. The title of the work shall appear on all such copies. In the case of a translation, the original title of the work shall appear in any case on all the said copies.

Comment: @Andrei while that is only binding for development countries, most country laws just codify something akin to that in their own laws.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the provision in the appendix. Good read. I am not arguing against you. It may be that many jurisdictions have such a provision to name the author, but it feels unnecessarily prescriptive to me. What if the author wants to remain completely anonymous, but at the same time, they want to license others to use their work without naming them in any form? From what you describe, this would be illegal, unless the law also prescribes that contrary to normal practice, the license takes precedence over that law. Again, I am aware I'm nitpicking almost beside the point.

Comment: While that answer is generally of a high quality, `License fees for recording a cover version (...) are usually mandatory to be available` is probably US-specific. Given that the original question has a UK tag, I would suggest to remove it (and the details of the pricing scheme) unless you have a source for UK compulsory licenses.

Comment: So when artists add another artist as writer "to cover themselves" they still require permission? I cannot for instance write Christmas lyrics to Hallelujah, slap Leonard Cohen on as writer and release it. That seems to be the common pattern now but presumably the original author just allows it for the cash :)

Comment: At the Harry Fox page I found only licenses relevant to sound recordings, not to covers.  Did I overlook something?  I am skeptical that a mechanical license prohibits changes to the lyrics; the concept was developed, after all, for player piano rolls.  Of course it's possible that subsequent developments in the law have some bearing on lyrics, but in general music and lyrics are separable.  If you have to give me a license to record your song with its original lyrics and also without lyrics, how can you prevent me from recording it with new lyrics?

Comment: @phoog mechanical licenses are to make recordings of the song for cover purposes. You didn't overlook it, but that *is* what they offer. The wording of a mechanical license usually excludes altering the text, and they usually bundle the text and sound - you more likely may alter the sound to suit your style.

Comment: For a public performance, "alteration again is not within the scope of such a license" - but if OP had secured a public performance license and then not performed the exact copyrighted song version, no one would have noticed or cared.  I doubt any live concert performance has *ever* perfectly matched the copyrighted song version in every detail, if only as a result of errors or gaps in performer ability or skill.

Answer (score 10):

Trish’s answer covers the main point: you need a license, and the license can prevent certain uses such as modified lyrics. There’s a side note though: sometimes, you *can* use copyrighted works without a license. Is it one of those cases?

### Fair dealing: can I perform (without a license) in a "private congregational church setting"?

Almost certainly not.

A limited amount of use of copyrighted works is allowed under various, jurisdiction-dependent provisions. In the [uk](/questions/tagged/uk), the name of that doctrine is ["fair dealing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_dealing).

The exact amount and scope depends a lot on the jurisdiction, but they almost always cover critical commentary of various forms (a newspaper can print a photograph of someone’s painting to call it ugly, or a politician’s speech to call them a liar; Wikipedia articles can put up film posters in the article about the film; parodies only work if the original work is kept sufficiently recognizable, but they are allowed).

In *some* jurisdictions, certain small-scale uses are exempt. For instance, [france](/questions/tagged/france) has a statute provision for "private and free-entry showings restricted to the family circle" ([link to statute, in French](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000006278917/2009-04-27/)).

I could not find any such provision in UK law in my (admittedly quick) search for UK copyright exemptions, and the government’s "copyright for non-lawyers" website [lists no such exemption](https://copyrightservice.co.uk/copyright/p27_work_of_others).

Furthermore, even assuming there are such provisions in UK law or jurisprudence, I doubt a "private congregational church setting" is covered. For instance, in France’s (somewhat) generous terms outlined above, it would not be. If the service is open to any who would like to come, even if *in practice* the same people show up every Sunday, that would be a death blow to any argument that the setting is "private" and small-scale.

Comment: What rules would apply to the act of showing a piece of work in development to other people for purposes of soliciting judgment as to whether it's good enough *to justify the time and effort required to pursue a license*?  If a work isn't going to be good enough to justify such effort, I suspect most copyright holders would prefer not to be bothered by licensing inquiries for it.

Comment: You could argue that "showing a piece in development" does not constitute distribution (that depends on who you show it to, in what circumstances etc.). Otherwise, the exact same rules apply - you want to use it, you need a license. If the copyright holders "would prefer not to be bothered", it means you have no license, not that you can do whatever you please.

Comment: There's a difference between 'do whatever you please' and 'do some things that are sufficiently trifling that asking permission would do more harm than doing the action without permission'.

Comment: Note that if a plausible outcome of asking for permission to do X would be that the copyright holder says "You may do X for $10" and the person wanting to perform the action paying $10, then doing the action without permission would deprive the copyright holder of $10.  If, however, the result would be "I won't authorize a distribution of a recording with altered lyrics unless I can listen to it first", then asking for permission before producing a demo recording would be a waste of time for all concerned.  To be sure, one might want to determine the likelihood of a license being granted...

Comment: ...before investing in a professional-quality studio recording of the song that may be unmarketable, and get a demo recording that's good enough for a copyright holder to be willing to specify terms under which it would agree to license a studio recording which substantially matches the one supplied, possibly with some specified alternations, with a proviso that while the copyright holder would need to hear the final product before approval, such approval would not be granted if the recording is consistent with the agreement.

Comment: Anything is possible in terms of licensing contracts, mechanisms for enforcement and so on. The business reality, however, is that most copyrights are held by a handful of companies constituted for that sole purpose. You either get a license under the standard terms that are offered to everyone, or you wave enough money under their nose to get a human to listen and negotiate with you (I haven’t done this but I guess the starting price is at least $10k).

Comment: If your point is that the entire legal-political-economic system of copyright (or even intellectual property in general) is unduly burdening small-scale creators, I wholeheartedly agree with you, but that has no incidence on the question of what the law currently is.

Comment: Nobody really knows "what the law currently is", because key aspects are left to the judgment of whoever is deciding cases.  Nothing in the statutes would unambiguously prevent someone who makes a copy of a picture for inclusion in a letter asking for permission to use the artwork in some fashion from being ordered to pay $400 because they committed copyright infringement when making a copy of the picture without permission, but everybody acts as though the law makes exceptions for such practices because almost everything would grind to a halt if it didn't.

Comment: From what I can tell, according to the *actual state of US law right now*, if a work is being used for some particular purpose which has not been considered in any previous fair-use analysis, the question of whether or not that constitutes "fair use" would depend solely upon whether a trial-court fact finder thinks it should be, and whether appeals-court judges think that it could reasonably be viewed as the trial-court judge viewed it.  There is no exhaustive list of purposes which would be sufficiently compelling as to "trump" the other factors; all one can do is hope judges are reasonable.